# How to block possibility to edit/drag impoly in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide

I create a polygon on image_area in matlab. 
I used impoly. 
But after creation polygon. 
I need to block possibility to move and drag impoly (ROI is already created). 
I don't know  how I should do it ?

I would appreciate for any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [makeConstrainToRectFcn](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/makeconstraintorectfcn.html) such that it is a rectangle encompassing your ROI, then whenever you try to move the latter it won't work. You can also, after creating the ROI, set the `setVerticesDraggable` method to false in order to prevent vertices from being dragged.

Sample code (adapted from example by the Mathworks):

```
clc
clear

figure
imshow('gantrycrane.png');
h = impoly(gca, [188,30; 189,142; 93,141; 13,41; 14,29]);

%// Get currentposition
Pos = getPosition(h);

%// Prevent draggable vertices
setVerticesDraggable(h,0);

%// Set up rectangle to prvent movement of ROI
fcn = makeConstrainToRectFcn('impoly', [min(Pos(:,1)) max(Pos(:,1))], [min(Pos(:,2)) max(Pos(:,2))]);

%// Apply function
h.setPositionConstraintFcn(fcn);
```

which results in this kind of situation (with red rectangle for illustration):

[image]

Comment: sure! If that answers your question please mark the answer as accepted (green checkmark below its score) to close the thread. thanks!