# Matlab - Set Resizeable to False with impoly

Tags: matlab, roi

I'm trying to disable resizing of an ROI created with impoly in Matlab.

This link seems to work for ellipse etc, but not for a polygon! -> http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imroi.setresizable.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Harry

EDIT: Apologies, below is the relevant code :)

```
% Set Caudate & Putamen ROI's
LPutamen = impoly(gca,[LPP1; LPP2; LPP3; LPP4]);
RPutamen = impoly(gca,[RPP1; RPP2; RPP3; RPP4]);
LCaudate = impoly(gca,[LCP1; LCP2; LCP3; LCP4; LCP5]);
RCaudate = impoly(gca,[RCP1; RCP2; RCP3; RCP4; RCP5]);

setResizeable(LPutamen, false);
```

Etc.

Comment: Please publish your code within the body of your post so it will be easier for others to review and answer. Using inessential external links makes reviewing and answering questions time consuming and counter-productive.

Comment: Thew answer can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377867/how-to-block-possibility-to-edit-drag-impoly-in-matlab  so vote to close as duplicate I guess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to block possibility to edit/drag impoly in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377867/how-to-block-possibility-to-edit-drag-impoly-in-matlab)

Comment: Absolute heroes both of you, thank you!!